# OL3 How to reproject vector layer on fly (ol 3.14)

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, geojson, proj

I have a map in OL 3.14 with a WMTS in a specific epsg.
I add a WMS layer in an other projection and it's ok, OL reproject right.
But with a vector Layer (geoJson, in the same projection as WMS), Openlayers don't display my feauture.

For my local projection, I use proj4.

My code :

```
var projectionL = ol.proj.get('EPSG:2154');
var projectionCC = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3946');

var ortho2013Extend= [1372000.0,5207000.0,1403020.0000000002 , 5238000.0];
//11 niveau de tuilage
var matrixIds = new Array(11);
//donc 11 niveaux resolution à gérer
var resolutions = new Array(11);

var size = ol.extent.getWidth(ortho2013Extend) / 302;
for (var z = 0; z < 11; ++z) {
  // generate resolutions and matrixIds arrays for this WMTS
  resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
  matrixIds[z] = z;
}
var ortho2013=new ol.layer.Tile({
  opacity: 0.7,
  extent:ortho2013Extend,
  source: new ol.source.WMTS({
    url: 'https://sigar.agglo-larochelle.fr/CeramikServer/rest/wmts/cdalr/ortho2013?',
    layer: 'ortho2013',
    matrixSet: projectionCC,
    format: 'image/jpeg',
    transparente:true,
    projection: projectionCC,
    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
      origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(ortho2013Extend),
      resolutions: resolutions,
      matrixIds: matrixIds,
      tileSize:302
    }),
    style: 'default'
  })
})
var feuxSonoresLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'feux_sonores_cc46.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        projection:projectionL
    })
});
map = new ol.Map({
    layers:[ortho2013, pluLayer, wmsHotSpotWifi, feuxSonoresLayer],
    target: 'map',
    //aucun controle
    //controls:[],
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: projectionCC,
        center: [1377000,5227000],
        extent: ortho2013Extend,
        zoom:14
    })
});
```

I have found some examples but in old version (3.8) and it used ol.source.GeoJSON, but this source doesn't exist now.

How to do ?

Comment: Are you receiving an error? Do logs give you any clues as to what might be happening?

Comment: I assume the GeoJSON is going to change so you can't just project it to the CRS of the Map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct your vector layer definition (the solution has been tested).

In below definition, you use a `projection` option that does not exist in the current [`ol.source.Vector`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) API.

`var feuxSonoresLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'feux_sonores_cc46.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
      projection:projectionL
  })
});`

Replace it with:

`var feuxSonoresLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'feux_sonores_cc46.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
          defaultDataProjection: projectionCC
        })
    })
});`

GeoJSON recommended data projection is EPSG 4326. OpenLayers 3 implicitly uses it.
The simplest choice is to use GeoJSON with EPSG:4326 projection coordinates.

Otherwise, if you choose to keep using a local projection for your GeoJSON (deduced from your file name `feux_sonores_cc46.geojson`, `CC46` = `EPSG:3946`), you need to specify it explicitly  with option `defaultDataProjection` available within [`ol.format.GeoJSON`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.1/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html)

You can also replace `projectionCC` variable with 'EPSG:3946'. As long as the projection is already loaded, using `'EPSG:3946'` instead will make an implicit call to `ol.proj.get('EPSG:3946')` behind the scene.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try this monday and I keep yourself update